# Obtain client connected time

Tags: php

I made a web page for showing videos to the user through HTML5 player. However, because of the limited resource, I would like to restrict their video play time. So the problem that I fact is how could I know/obtain the video played time of each users by using PHP? That means I would like to know how long does the user keep connect to my server for video watching. I don't want to depend on font end and want to do it all on back end. It was troubling me few days. Please give an aid. Thanks.

For more reference, my code is referring to: http://www.tuxxin.com/php-mp4-streaming/

Thanks again.

Comment: Are you asking to limit per video or total play time? And do you need it to stop playing at that limit, or do you want to allow it to complete the current playback and prevent subsequent playbacks? Are your users authenticated (ie do they have to log in to play video)?

Comment: Thanks. All users need authentication. I would like to limit their total play time and stop playing at that limit. The authentication and the stop playing part were completed and I setup a timer at font end(JS) to count down the user credit(play time left). When page unload(onbeforeunload event), the result will be sent to the PHP part. But it is not reliably enough for using JS to count and send out the result(JS code edit by user, fake HTTP request, use task manager to kill the browser process...etc). So could PHP identify when the connection(video transmission) was exactly aborted? Thanks.

Comment: So presumably you can record how much data has been sent in the while loop, and check that value against the limit? The only problem that I can see is that the player will buffer additional data, plus the user may skip forward and back and I don't think there's anything that you can do about that since you're using a third party player. You state that you don't want to rely on a front-end solution, but would you consider the front-end working WITH the back-end, so you could have a player let you know what's been played and within a % of the server times you could say you trust the front-end?